# Is the following way correct to find occurrences of character in string

Tags: java, string

```
//program to find number of occurrences of "i" in string
public class NumberOfChar {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String input="this is String";
        String find="i";
        String result=" ";
        String newResult = " ";
        for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++)
        {
            String search=input.charAt(i)+" ";
            String newSearch=search.trim();

            if(newSearch.equals(find))
            {
                    newResult=result.trim();
                    result+=search;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Number of ocuurances:"+newResult.length());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not execute it and check?

Comment: Just one line `int count = input.replaceAll("[^" + find + "]", "").length();`

Comment: Your code will break for {String input = "ithis is Stringi";} and it will print - Number of ocuurances:7

Comment: you are using (char+" ").trim() to convert a char to a String. No, that is not a sensible conversion. What if char had been a whitespace character?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class NumberOfChar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "this is String";
        char find = 'i';
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            if (input.charAt(i) == find) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Number of ocuurances:" + count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `chars()` method of a string returns a stream, which you may filter and count:

```
    String input = "this is String";
    char find = 'i';
    System.out.println("Number of occurrences: " 
            + input.chars().filter(c -> find==c).count());
```